# Creating photos to use as ImageButtons in my app - regarding size

Tags: android, image, layout, dimension

When creating images to place as ImageButtons in my app, what is the staple rule to go by in terms of width?  I know each phone will resize accordingly with a wrap_content parameter, but what is the universal width I should be using?  These are basic titles for each layout I am using, as reference.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on what kind of icon you are creating (menu, app launcher, etc..). Icon sizes also depend on screen density.

Check out [Icon Design Guidelines](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design.html).

Comment: Ahhh ok, now what about images used in the app, not the icons themselves?  I developed my images scaled to a width of around 400 pixels as I developed using an motorola android 2, as long as the images are set to wrap_content, I won't have to resize for each density level right?

Comment: Afaik images are not resized unles you explicitly resize them in code. Try your code on different emulator screen sizes.